# How to send a notification according to user's interest?

Tags: android, android-fragments, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Many have you have noticed that sometimes we gets notifications according to our needs and Interest.

***For Example:*** Suppose you are using any Hotel Booking App, You entered the city and checked some hotels but didn't booked any hotel and closed the App. You will notice, after few hours or days they will send you notifications according to what I checked on their App(Like some offers or Planning to visit "xyz" city?) How they send such notifications? What they use for last searched cities/hotels of each user and send notification accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [fabric](https://fabric.io) and [firebase](https://firebase.google.com). These provide a very efficient way to keep a track of user's activity over the application..  Now all you have to do is initialise either of these in your application and keep a track of user activities.
And after that you will know the interests of your users and you can notify them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is how do you gather the data to use in the notifications.

For each user you can save events and details on the visited places (in this examples, the hotels in the application) at each step, each activity, each action. You can save all these in the database and with a cron you can send a notification for the users who visited some parts of the application but have not made a booking/purchase today.